# Room Light Switch Malfunction

Tags: electrical, switch, light-fixture

I have a standard, on/off light switch for the fan/light in a room.  The past 2 days the light does not want to turn on when the switch is flipped "up" it wants to turn on when the switch is almost in a half-way position between "up" and "down"

The light will remain off when the switch is "down" and the light will remain off when the switch is completely flipped "up".  There has been no electrical work done, no storms nothing altered or changed in that room or the home.

Is this switch just wearing out (it's only about 8 months old) or what could be causing this issue?

Comment: If you still have the (dated) receipt, it should be a warranty issue and replaced with the same or similar one.

Comment: Is the room perchance on a 3 way switch? Is there potentially another switch that might be able to control that light?

Comment: @THiebert -> no it is not a 3 way switch.

Comment: @Criggie -> thanks for the tip!  My local box hardware store swapped it out no questions asked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your assessment would be correct as it sounds like a bad switch to me. Age is really no factor. I cannot begin to tell you the number of new products I've bought and/or installed over the years that we're bad straight out of the box.

$2.00 and 5 minutes and you should be switching right again!!!

Answer (score 1):

If the switch has failed this quickly it was probably cheap construction grade switch. I would pick up a spec grade switch yes it will cost a few dollars more than the 98 cent (or cheaper) switch but better quality is worth it in my opinion.